# what sensors to use in touch sensitive furniture

Tags: sensor, led, keyboard

I'm trying to make a wooden table with a touch-sensitive top, made up of a mosaic of small wooden pieces resembling scrabble playing pieces separated by thin glass separations. each wooden piece would be connected to its own sensor(s) and also to LED lights that would glow through the glass around the wooden piece touched. What would be the appropriate sensor to use? I want the table to be as rigid as possible, and i don't want that clicking feel when you press any wooden block...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capacitive touch sensor for this sort of thing -- no pressing of any buttons is required.

You need to create 3 things for this to work:

- A sensor PCB which has two metal pads. Mount this inside each of your wooden pieces *near the surface*.  When the user's finger gets close enough, it changes the capacitance between the pads.  See [this application note](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-925.pdf) for some tips on how to design the sensor.
- A sensor IC wired to these two metal pads which senses the changes in capacitance.  Something like the [AD7147](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-to-digital-converters/capacitance-to-digital-converters/ad7147/products/product.html) could work as the measurement chip.
- A controller of some sort to communicate with the sensor IC and light up the appropriate LEDs.